# mini_racer was resolved to 0.8.0, which depends on libv8-node

Tags: ruby, jekyll, bundle

```
Installing libv8-node 18.16.0.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Users/nueon/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/libv8-node-18.16.0.0/ext/libv8-node
C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile
C:/Users/nueon/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/libv8-node-18.16.0.0/ext/libv8-node/builder.rb:12:in `build_libv8!':
failed to download node 18.16.0 (Libv8::Node::BuilderError)
    from C:/Users/nueon/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/libv8-node-18.16.0.0/ext/libv8-node/location.rb:30:in `install!'
    from extconf.rb:15:in `<main>'
==== in
C:/Users/nueon/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/libv8-node-18.16.0.0/ext/libv8-node
==== running
C:/Users/nueon/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/libv8-node-18.16.0.0/libexec/download-node

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Users/nueon/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/libv8-node-18.16.0.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Users/nueon/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.2.0/libv8-node-18.16.0.0/gem_make.out

  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:119:in `run'
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:27:in `build'
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:187:in `build_extension'
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:221:in `block in build_extensions'
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:218:in `each'
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:218:in `build_extensions'
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/installer.rb:843:in `build_extensions'
  C:/Users/nueon/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:72:in `build_extensions'
  C:/Users/nueon/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in `install'
  C:/Users/nueon/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:201:in `install'
  C:/Users/nueon/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
  C:/Users/nueon/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'
  C:/Users/nueon/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:156:in  `do_install'
  C:/Users/nueon/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:147:in `block in worker_pool'
  C:/Users/nueon/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
  C:/Users/nueon/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
  C:/Users/nueon/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  C:/Users/nueon/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
  C:/Users/nueon/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing libv8-node (18.16.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  mini_racer was resolved to 0.8.0, which depends on
    libv8-node
```

pls help me

also bundle not working not starting

Comment: Please [reformat your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) using the linked guide. Properly formatting your post increases the likelihood of you receiving a constructive response.